# upload report for android automated and unit test cases

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, sonarqube, jacoco, sonarqube-scan

I want to upload coverage report for both android automated and unit test cases.
If i give report path for only android automated test case file which is .ec file.
then it give  coverage on dashboard.But if I give path of both .ec & .exec file then it does not give coverage for both on dashboard.

below is the code

```
property "sonar.jacoco.reportPath", "${buildDir}/outputs/code-coverage/connected/flavors/ELECTRONIC/coverage.ec,${buildDir}/jacoco/testElectronicDebugUnitTest.exec"
```

Please help how to upload coverage report for both automated and unit test cases.

Comment: And what about the log ? Any warning, error, info ?

Comment: Missing blame information for the following files: This may lead to missing/broken features in SonarQube                                                                    BUILD SUCCESSFUL